# OpenCV Kalman Filter stack overflow

Tags: c++, opencv, kalman-filter

I'm trying to implement a kalman filter for 3D tracking in OpenCV 2.2. The state variables are the coordinates x,y,z followed by the velocities Vx,Vy and Vz and I can only measure x,y and z.

I used an example from the book Learning OpenCV from O'reilly to get started, but when I tried to adapt the example to my problem things got a little confusing.

This is my implementation (I've tried to reduce the code to just the relevant parts, and I've commented a lot to hopefully ease the reading).

```
    CvKalman* kalman = cvCreateKalman( 6, 3, 0 );

    // Setting the initial state estimates to [0,0,0,0,0,0].
    CvMat* x_k = cvCreateMat( 6, 1, CV_32FC1 );
    cvZero(x_k);

    // Setting the a posteriori estimate to zero.
    cvZero(kalman->state_post);

    // Creating the process noise vector.
    CvMat* w_k = cvCreateMat( 2, 1, CV_32FC1 );

    // Creating the measurement vector.
    CvMat* z_k = cvCreateMat( 6, 1, CV_32FC1 );
    cvZero( z_k );

    // Initializing the state transition matrix.
    float F_kalman[] = { 1,0,0,0.05,0,0, 0,1,0,0,0.05,0, 0,0,1,0,0,0.05, 0,0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1 };
    memcpy( kalman->transition_matrix->data.fl, F_kalman, sizeof(F_kalman));

    // Initializing the other necessary parameters for the filter.
    cvSetIdentity( kalman->measurement_matrix); 
    cvSetIdentity( kalman->process_noise_cov, cvRealScalar(1e-2) );
    cvSetIdentity( kalman->measurement_noise_cov, cvRealScalar(1e-1) );
    cvSetIdentity( kalman->error_cov_post, cvRealScalar(1));

    // Updates the measurement vector with my sensor values, wich were in the variable xyz (an array of CvScalar).
    cvSetReal1D(z_k,0,xyz[i].val[0]);
    cvSetReal1D(z_k,1,xyz[i].val[1]);
    cvSetReal1D(z_k,2,xyz[i].val[2]);

    cvKalmanPredict(kalman,0);
    cvKalmanCorrect(kalman,z_k);
```

The problem is, when I run the code I get a "Unhandled exception at 0x55a3e757 in test.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow." at the cvKalmanCorrect line.

Perhaps I've initialized one of the matrices to the wrong expected size, but I'm really lost on how to check this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Please use opencv compiled pdbs and dlls in your current working folder to identify the exact problem. If source code available in your system it will show the where crash occurs this will give you some idea.

Comment: Sorry but this answer was a bit confusing to me, could you rewrite it please? Thank you

Comment: If you include the debug information for opencv we could see where in cvKalmanCorrect the error occurs. Wihtout that we only now that it happens somewhere in cvKalmanCorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is in the size of z_k, it should be (3,1) and not (6,1), because in it that are only the 3 scalar of the measurement, indeed it is the measurement array.